# things and people who matter vs things and people that matter

Tags: conjunctions

> Remember to focus on the things and people **who/that** matter during these times of trouble.

I'm trying to write this phrase, following the Chicago Manual guidelines, which suggest using **who** for people, but since we have both **things** and **people** here, for some reasons, **that** seems better.

I also know there is a rule of thumb to use the closest word in some cases: "there *is a vase*, some pencils, two books..."

Comment: You might feel more comfortable applying that "rule of thumb" (match to the nearest word) if you reverse the sequence of the two "syntactically incompatible" nouns: *Focus on the **people and things that** matter*. But it's a very fine point of style (just because CMOS *recommends* using "who" for "people" doesn't mean it's actually ungrammatical to refer to *people that you know*, for example.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the sequence [*people **that** I know*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=people+that+I+know%2Cpeople+who+I+know&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeople%20that%20I%20know%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%20who%20I%20know%3B%2Cc0) is twice as common in Google Books as *people **who** I know*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, perhaps, *people whom I know* should be added to that search.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: You're absolutely right, of course. I never even *thought* of using "whom" there (almost completely abandoned by me personally decades ago). But even if I [add everything for "who" and "whom" together](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=people+that+I+know%2C%28people+who+I+know%29%2B%28people+whom+I+know%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeople%20that%20I%20know%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28people%20who%20I%20know%29%20%2B%20%28people%20whom%20I%20know%29%3B%2Cc0) the preference for "that" is much greater.